# Scrapy performance decreases after 5minutes

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create a small website crawler using scrapy. I have 100Mbps Fiber Internet.

Scrapy starts parsing at 350pages per min.
Than the speeds starts going down until it hovers around 20 pages per min.

I'm using the following (relatively simple) spider.

```
class DefaultSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "default"
    session_id = -1
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),callback='insert_linkDB',follow=True)]

    db = DBConnector()
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in listurl:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.insert_linkDB)


    def insert_linkDB(self, response):
        DB.insert(response.url, response.text)
        for link in self.rules[0].link_extractor.extract_links(response):
            if((link.url.find(self.currentDomain)>=0) and (link.url.find("psml")==-1)):
                yield scrapy.Request(url=link.url, callback=self.insert_linkDB)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` on or off? Does inserting in the DB or not have an influence?

Comment: The DB is running on an SSD drive with a Quad CPU. AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED is OFF.

Comment: couldn't it be possible that the crawler already covered most links on the site? Also try checking number of duplicated requests.

Comment: To avoid double insertion in DB i use an update function that prevent adding the website if the url matches with one already in the DB.
But scrapy is indeed downloading them again. But how can I prevent it from doing that ?